# Prevent Netflix credits zoom-out

Tags: netflix

At the end of shows on Netflix, the credits zoom out to show an advertisement for the next episode (even including light *spoilers* in the form of an episode description!).

This sucks, it really ruins the impact of well-designed credits cuts on episodes like *Breaking Bad*'s "Ozymandias" and *Bojack*'s "Fish out of Water". It also makes it hard to spot guest actors (more important on animated shows where you can't just see them and can't place a familiar voice). You can zoom back in by clicking, but it really ruins the immersion.

I've figured out how to stop the next episode from autoplaying so that I can at least listen to the whole song, but I'd really like to stop this altogether.

User-scripts or extensions would be fine!

Comment: There's a petition to stop Netflix from doing this which needs a _lot_ more signatures: https://www.change.org/p/neil-hunt-stop-netflix-from-shrinking-credits-after-movie-ends Also complain to Netflix _every_ time this happens, at least if it ruins an ending for you. In the meantime I'm watching Netflix on an older Roku XD which doesn't do this. This is a very disturbing precedent however, in that they're on the way to making Netflix as annoying as cable TV, when its initial success was largely due to being able to watch things uninterrupted!